# External library mock patch used in all tests doesnt work when tests run together

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I am using Python's mock library along with unittest. I am writing unit tests for a class that uses a function of an external library in one of its methods. Depending on the case, this function returns different values.

So let's say I wanna test class A:

```
from external_library import function_foo

class A(object):
...
```

In my test class, in order to use the values returned by the function from the external library, I create a patch, and only import class A after defining the patch. However, I need to use this function in all my test methods, and in each method it returns different values.

My test class is as follows:

```
class TestA(TestCase):

    @patch('external_library.function_foo', side_effect=[1, 2, 3])    
    def test_1(self, *patches):

       from module import class A
       obj = A()
       ...

    @patch('external_library.function_foo', side_effect=[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])    
    def test_2(self, *patches):

       from module import class A
       obj = A()
       ...

    ...
```

I have 10 tests and only 1 (the first one) passes when I run all of them together, for the rest, I get `StopIteration` error. However, **if I run each one of them individually, they all pass**.

I have tried using `with patch('external_library.function_foo', side_effect=[...])` in each method, but the outcome was the same. I also tried creating only once the patch in the `setUp` method, starting it, reassigning the side_effect within each method, and stopping in `tearDown`, but it didn't work.

Any ideas on what might work in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The caveat is, the second time you import a module, [it would not be loaded again](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache), you get the same module object as the first time you imported.

When you first run "test_1", `external_library.function_foo` replaced by a `Mock` object, let's name it `mock_a`. Then your "module" get imported for the first time, python will load it, means, execute code inside "module", which will bind name "function_foo" to object "mock_a" in the namespace of "module", save "module" object to `sys.modules`. This time your test will pass, and `side_effect` of `mock_a` get consumed.

Next is "test_2", `external_library.function_foo` replaced by a `Mock` object, name it to `mock_b`. Then import "module", this time it would not be loaded again, but populate from `sys.modules`, you get the same module object as in "test_1". In the namespace of this module object, name "function_foo" is still bound to object `mock_a`, not the newly created `mock_b`. Because `side_effect` of `mock_a` has already consumed, `StopIteration` error raised.

You should apply patch to where a *name* is looked up, but not where it is defined:

```
@patch('module.function_foo', side_effect=[1, 2, 3])    
def test_1(self, patch):
    ...
```

Read more detail on the ["Where to patch" section of the manual of `patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the great explanation @georgexsh, I got it working by replacing the `external_library.function_foo` by `package.module.function_foo`