# Patch works on individual pytest file, does not call code under test as test suite,

Tags: mocking, pytest, python-unittest.mock

I've seen the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65331893/how-do-i-patch-a-function-imported-by-an-imported-class?rq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285951/external-library-mock-patch-used-in-all-tests-doesnt-work-when-tests-run-togethe?rq=2), but I am having trouble.

my code file:
index.py
from paho.mqtt,client import Client

```
mqtt_connected = False
mqtt_client = Client("my-client") 
TOPIC = "topic"

def _send_message(msg, client):
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    print(f"Here in send message with client {mqtt_client}")
    client.connect("test.mosquitto.org",1883, 60)      
    response = client.publish(TOPIC, msg)
    return response.is_published
```

test_mqtt.py
from unittest.mock import patch

```
class Test_Mqtt:

    msg = "My message"        

    def test_send(self):
        from fsas_lambda import index

        with patch('fsas_lambda.index.Client' ) as mock_client:
           # mock_client.return_value = index.Client()
           index._send_message(DBirth(self.event), mock_client)

           print(f"Mock client = {mock_client}")
           print(f" Client methos calls: {mock_client.method_calls}")
    
           mock_client.publish.assert_called()
           assert False
```

When run as `pytest` this fails with  `AssertionError: Expected 'publish' to have been called.`

The only prints are from pytest:

```
Mock client = <MagicMock name='Client' id='1443899989344'>
 Client methos calls: []
```

When run from  `pytest <path>/test_mqtt.py`  it gets all the way to the `assert False`

I also get prints from the code under test:

```
Here in send message with client <MagicMock name='Client' id='2589477813456'>
Mock client = <MagicMock name='Client' id='2589477813456'>
Client methos calls: [call.connect('test.mosquitto.org', 1883, 60),
call.publish('topic', 'My message')]
```

I get the same results with or without this line
`# mock_client.return_value = index.Client()`

Also tried this patch with no change:
`with patch('paho.mqtt.client.Client' ) as mock_client:`